# Missing tables after being created in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to create a a schema with 4 tables, but when I run my code there is only 1 table created (WFacts). Any Ideas?

```
private static String wdft_query="CREATE TABLE WDayFactTracks ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,dayAcomplishedPerWeek INTEGER)";
private static String wf_query="CREATE TABLE WFacts ( _id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT UNIQUE, wday REFERENCES WDayFactTracks ( _id ) ))";
private static String wt_query="CREATE TABLE WTracks (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT, currentDate DATE, weight REAL NOT NULL, wday REFERENCES WDayFactTracks ( _id ) );";
private static String wu_query="CREATE TABLE WUser ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, name TEXT NOT NULL, wtrack_id INT REFERENCES WTracks ( _id ), wfact REFERENCES WFacts ( _id ) );";
public ModeloBD(Context context,  CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, BDName, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public ModeloBD(Context context){
    super(context, BDName, null, version_t);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //db.execSQL(BDQuery); crea solo una tabla
    db.execSQL(wdft_query);
    db.execSQL(wf_query);
    db.execSQL(wt_query);
    db.execSQL(wu_query);       
    //inicializacion de datos
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO WUser (_id,name,wtrackid,wfact) VALUES (1,test,,)");


}
```

Comment: You miss semicolon in the end of the first two queries

Comment: The only one that is created is WFacts

Comment: Did you fix the errors and try again?

Comment: Your `INSERT` command will definitely fail, but you have not shown any error messages. Furthermore, you do not have [enabled foreign keys](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys).

Comment: 1. I fix the semicolon and it does not work the db is not created properly.

Comment: How can I enable foreing keys? Does someone knows a more complex example? (All the examples I have found uses just one table) BTW I deleted the insert instruction